# How to start apk file install right after "Unknown Sources" are enabled in Nougat?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-install-apk

How to start apk file install right after "Unknown Sources" are enabled in Android Nougat? In my activity I download file on button click, then I call intent to start install my apk file. Then I am redirected to Settings to enabled unknown sources, after I return to my application nothing happens, I need click to my file once again to start install.

Is it possible to start file install right after I return to my app from settings screen where I enabled unknown sources?

On Android 8+ everything is ok.

Thanks!